# <p:row> renders incorrect result

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have been working on this problem from last two days. I went through the apis possibly I could refer to but no luck.

I have been using `ui:repeat` as `jsf facelet` to render data with rows and columns

**Code for reference**

```
<ui:repeat var="pendingRequestItem" value="#{oqHomeController.allRequests}" > --JSF
    <p:row rendered="#{oqHomeController.renderPendingRequest}> -- PRIMEFACES FOR ROW
       <td><h:outputText value="#{pendingRequestItem.title}" /></td>
       <td><h:outputText value="#{oqHomeController.pendingCount}" /></td>
    </p:row>
</ui:repeat>
```

*And the above code is resulting in the following which is very strange.*

```
<tbody>
       <td>Request for Quote 1</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>DTHEME1</td>
       <td>4</td>
</tbody>
```

*I hope it should be*

```
<tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Request for Quote 1</td>
         <td>1</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>DTHEME1</td>
         <td>4</td>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `<td>`, have you tried using `<p:column>`? The result WILL be what you ask for...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<p:dataTable>` it seems that is what you are looking for:

```
<p:dataTable var="pendingRequestItem" value="#{oqHomeController.allRequests}">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{pendingRequestItem.title}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{oqHomeController.pendingCount}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks. I however went with `ui:repeat`. I put the entire one in `<p:row/>` to solve the problem.